# PayPal Checkout SDK breakdown object raising error

Tags: typescript, paypal, checkout

I am attempting to handle payments using the PayPal Checkout SDK on a storefront I am developing. I am attempting to add a shipping amount of $10 USD to all orders. Looking at the SDK [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-MISSING_REQUIRED_PARAMETER) I believe I'll need to use the [amount](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-amount_with_breakdown) and [breakdown](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-amount_with_breakdown) objects.

#### Code

```
      createOrder: (data, actions) => {
        return actions.order.create({
          purchase_units: [{
            amount: {
              breakdown: {
                item_total: {currency_code: "USD", value: "32"},
                shipping: {currency_code: "USD", value: "10"}
              }
            }
          }]
        })
      }
```

#### Error

```
Uncaught Error: /v2/checkout/orders returned status 400 (Corr ID: 46c2d60c192b).

{"name":"INVALID_REQUEST","message":"Request is not well-formed, syntactically incorrect, or violates schema.","debug_id":"46c2d60c192b","details":[{"field":"/purchase_units/@reference_id=='default'/amount/value","value":"","location":"body","issue":"MISSING_REQUIRED_PARAMETER","description":"A required field / parameter is missing."}],"links":[{"href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-MISSING_REQUIRED_PARAMETER","rel":"information_link","encType":"application/json"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

The amount itself needs a value and currency_code, separate from any extra object that gives a breakdown.

See the full example in the 6th bullet of [this documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/integrate/):

```
createOrder: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.order.create({
         "purchase_units": [{
            "amount": {
              "currency_code": "USD",
              "value": "100",
              "breakdown": {
                "item_total": {  /* Required when including the `items` array */
                  "currency_code": "USD",
                  "value": "100"
                }
              }
            },
            "items": [
              {
                "name": "First Product Name", /* Shows within upper-right dropdown during payment approval */
                "description": "Optional descriptive text..", /* Item details will also be in the completed paypal.com transaction view */
                "unit_amount": {
                  "currency_code": "USD",
                  "value": "50"
                },
                "quantity": "2"
              },
            ]
          }]
      });
    },
```